# Sql inner query select between two transaction

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, transactions, isolation-level, transaction-isolation

Need help in understanding inner query select reads between two transaction

```
UPDATE SER_NUMBERS SET SER_NUM = SER_NUM + 1 WHERE YEAR = 
(SELECT YEAR FROM (SELECT YEAR FROM SER_NUMBERS WHERE YEAR >= 1950
AND SER_NUM < 999 ORDER BY YEAR) WHERE ROWNUM =1)
```

I am updating SER_NUM = SER_NUM + 1 every time the query executes, the request are so intense that there could be thousands of request per second.

Question is that can two query transaction have a chance of reading same value from the inner select and two transaction updates the same value?

Is there a simple way to make Transaction-2 wait for the read until Transaction-1 finishes its update?

As I see from the oracle documentation the default isolation is Read committed

> (Oracle Database does not prevent other transactions from modifying
>   the data read by a query, that data can be changed  by other
>   transactions between two executions of the query. Thus, a transaction
>   that runs a given query twice can experience both nonrepeatable read
>   and phantoms.)

Any suggestion on best approach to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a simple way to make Transaction-2 wait for the read until Transaction-1 finishes its update?

In general, **Readers don't block writers, and writers don't block the readers.**

From the documentation,

> Transaction-Level Read Consistency
>
> Oracle Database also offers the option of enforcing transaction-level
>   read consistency. When a transaction runs in serializable mode, all
>   data accesses reflect the state of the database as of the time the
>   transaction began. Thus, the data seen by all queries within the same
>   transaction is consistent with respect to a single point in time,
>   except that queries made by a serializable transaction do see changes
>   made by the transaction itself. Transaction-level read consistency
>   produces repeatable reads and does not expose a query to phantoms.

Read more about [Data Concurrency and Consistency](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/consist.htm#CNCPT020)